# In Chime, how do I save an improved level coverage percentage?

Tags: chime

In Chime (an Xbox Live Arcade Game), how do I "save" in the Choose a Level menu with an improved coverage percentage?

It seems that no matter what I do, the new coverage percentage isn't saved into the "Choose a Level" screen.  After achieving a new high coverage percentage in 3-minute timed mode, I'm presented with a screen that allows me to play again, move on to the next level, or go to the main menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out my problem.  I'd been beating a past coverage percentage, but not the high score.  If I beat the previous high score, then both the coverage percentage and high score are saved.